# Change connection string petapoco

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, petapoco

I have 2 separate databases which I'm wanting to merge to be shared by one site. When someone logs in I have a check to see if the user exists in database one, if they aren't I check database 2, if they are in that database I want to switch to default connection string to database 2. The petapoco database is has auto-generated code it says not to change. so is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The PetaPoco Database object has 4 constructors:

```
    public Database(IDbConnection connection)
    public Database(string connectionString, string providerName)
    public Database(string connectionString, DbProviderFactory provider)
    public Database(string connectionStringName)
```

Use `Database(string connectionString, string providerName)` if you want to provide the connection string.